# Will a Reality Composer project file with 2 scenes play in Xcode?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am using Reality Composer and have 2 scenes in a project file.

Will both of those scenes play in my Augmented Reality app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many Reality Composer scenes in your AR app as you wish.

Here is a code snippet how you could read in Reality Composer scenes:

```
import RealityKit

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sceneUno = try! Experience.loadFirstScene()
    let sceneDos = try! Experience.loadSecondScene()
    let sceneTres = try! Experience.loadThirdScene()

    arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneUno)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneDos)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(sceneTres)
}
```

Also, you could read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191009/reality-composer-custom-collision-between-entities-of-different-scenes) to find out how to collide entities from different scenes. In other words, RealityKit app can mix and play several Reality Composer scenes at a time.

Comment: So even if I create multiple scenes in the reality composer file, in xcode contentview, the code has to be written as to which scenes to play?  When I used the default Experience.rcproject and added an additional scene to it, only the "box" scene would play.

Comment: Sorry @skynard, what do you mean saying "scene plays"? Animation? As you see in a link in my answer, you can mix 2 or more different scenes and they all can play simultaneously.

Comment: @skynard, have you tried to mix two RC scenes in RealityKit?

Comment: That worked perfectly.  That was my first bit of writing code.  Much appreciated.  I have not tried to mix 2 scenes.  We are creating an experience with audio so my big challange is to place nodes for audio and the avaudioplayer commands.  Any suggestions as to books or guides for those steps.

Comment: Create the next question on audio, please. Don`t mix two topics here)))))